# Click anywhere to remove class

Tags: jquery, function, drop-down-menu, callback, click

The sample code is here:
http://codepen.io/vincentccw/pen/loAwu

Basically what I want to do is creating a custom dropdown list using  tag but replaceable div button.

My problems is once I click on the div, the custom class will be added(drop down list appear), but then when I click on anywhere else the second time, I want to remove the class and hence back to original state. How should I do that?

```
$(function(){ 

$(".dButton").click(function(){
   $("div ul.customDropDownList").addClass("clickButtonReveal");
});     
$('body').click(function(){
if( $("div ul.customDropDownList").hasClass("clickButtonReveal") ){
      alert("remove class");
      $("div ul.customDropDownList").removeClass("clickButtonReveal");
      };
    });
});
```

For now both the click function will triggered at the same time....

Comment: can you explain clearly,unable to get your point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try [this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yEkdK)

```
$(".dButton").click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $("div ul.customDropDownList").addClass("clickButtonReveal");

});
```

Updated below content:

for more [info](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)

Comment: I got it working but can you explain how e.stopPropagation(); works?
I understand stopPropagation is to prevent the event from bubbling up the dom tree but that still doesn't explain how it works.

Comment: Yes, would you mind explaining the reason why this works? Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You could just stop propagation on button click:

```
$(".dButton").click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $("div ul.customDropDownList").addClass("clickButtonReveal");

});
```

Answer (score 3):

You could try this and check the id of your click target:

html:

```
<div id="test">

</div>
```

css:

```
#test{
    background-color:red;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
}
```

javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).click(function(e){
       if(e.target.id == 'test')
       {
           alert('Red box clicked!');
       }
       else
       {
           alert('Clicked something else');
       }
    })
})
```

Working example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/JXZhP/

Answer (score 0):

Use the jQuery one() function to remove whatever you need removed when the user clicks anywhere on the body of your page. one() triggers only once... so change your code to:

```
$(".dButton").click(function(){
  $("div ul.customDropDownList").addClass("clickButtonReveal");
  $('body').one(function(){
    $("div ul.customDropDownList").removeClass("clickButtonReveal")
  });
});
```

Just in case it is not clear: Remove the second function `$('body').click(function(){...})` in your code. this replaces all your code.

Comment: it would be better if we cache the value of `$("div ul.customDropDownList")` and use it again. DOM traversing is expensive :)

Comment: @sv_in It was to show the concept as I am sure there is lots of other code around that; but yes you are right ;P

Comment: I just added the comment for beginners like him to know about element caching. I have seen a lot of people who don't know about this simple thing.